# How do I check and return all same values from a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to make a function that checks a json file for all values that match the input, input being "property" = True

Basically I'm looking for a function to return item1 and item2

```
{"item1": {"property": True}, "item2": {"property": True}, "item3": {"property": False}}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That's not JSON, it's a Python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary comprehension with a condition.

```
data = {"item1": {"property": True}, "item2": {"property": True}, "item3": {"property": False}}

result = {key: value for key, value in data.items() if value['property']}
```

Comment: do you mean `{key: value .... }`

Comment: Yeah, I make that typo all the time

Answer (score 0):

Simple comprehension will do the trick:

```
tuple(k for k in d if d[k]["property"])
```